Is there a way to update an existing Azure storage account network rules with Bicep?
Is there a way to update existing storage account network rules with Bicep?
Here is a Bicep module I was drafting to do this, but I haven't found a way to successfully do this.
Specifically, this portion here is what I am having trouble with:
// Update the Storage Account Networking to allow VNet access
resource storageAccountNetwork 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/networkRules@2022-09-01' = {
  name: 'default'
  parent: storageAccount
  properties: {
    defaultAction: 'Deny' // Deny access by default
    virtualNetworkRules: [
      for subnetId in subnetIds: {
        id: subnetId
      }
    ]
    bypass: 'AzureServices'
  }
}

I tried the above module with no success. Does anyone know if this is possible, or of another way I can achieve this?

Just patch the virtualNetworkRules via Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts resource. When deploying, only modified properties will be overwritten, and unchanged properties will be skipped.

According to the documentation, there is no networkRules sub-resource. You will need to update the storage directly:
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  properties: {
    ...
    networkAcls: {
      defaultAction: 'Deny' // Deny access by default
      virtualNetworkRules: [
        for subnetId in subnetIds: {
          id: subnetId
        }
      ]
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
    }
  }
}

You can try to patch the existing storage account but not sure if it is the best approach:

Create a module to update your storage account (patch-storage.bicep):

param config {
  name: string
  location: string
  kind: string
  sku: object
  properties: object
}

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-05-01' = {
  name: config.name
  location: config.location
  kind: config.kind
  sku: config.sku
  properties: config.properties
}


From your main.bicep, get the existing configuration, update the network rules and call the mdule:

param storageAccountName string
param subnetIds array


// get a reference to the existing storage
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' existing = {
  name: storageAccountName
}

var virtualNetworkRules = [
  for subnetId in subnetIds: {
    id: subnetId
  }
]

// Merge existing properties with new networkAcls
var properties = union(storageAccount.properties, {
  networkAcls: {
    defaultAction: 'Deny' // Deny access by default
    virtualNetworkRules: virtualNetworkRules
    bypass: 'AzureServices'
  }
})

// Update the storage
module patchedStorage 'patch-storage.bicep' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  params: {
    config: {
      name: storageAccount.name
      location: storageAccount.location
      sku: storageAccount.sku
      kind: storageAccount.kind
      properties: properties
    }
  }
}


Hi Thomas, is there a way to structure this so it's just one bicep module, and referenced cleanly in the main like this? Just having a hard time wrapping my head around the provided solution.
//Re-use existing params (where no change) and apply new params (where change)
module patchedStorage 'modules/lms-web-app-storage-account-vnet-access.bicep' = {
name: storageAccountName
params: {
config: {
name: storageAccountName
location: storageAccountLocation
sku: storageAccountSku
kind: storageAccountKind
properties: properties
}
}
}

@jobatthemall, not really, otherwise you'll end up with circular dependency if the resource is defined multiple time in the same template. Also updated the bicep comments to make it clearer
